# Lambda function gives 502 internal server error when function declared async

Tags: node.js, async-await, aws-lambda

I have a HTTP GET event lambda function (LA) that internally invokes another lambda (LB).

The code for LA lambda

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
let lambda = new AWS.Lambda();

export function main(event, context, callback) {
  var params = {
    FunctionName: "app-dev-lb",
    InvocationType: "RequestResponse",
    LogType: "Tail",
    Payload: JSON.stringify("abc")
  };

  lambda.invoke(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      callback(null, failure(err));
    } else {
      callback(null, success(data.Payload));
    }
  });
}
```

The code for LB lambda

```
export async function main(event, context, callback) {
  callback(null, success({ name: "Abhi" }));
}
```

The above code for LA and LB lambda works fine and gives response 200 with `{ name: "Abhi" }` in response body.

But as as soon as I add `async` in LA lambda function, it gives response 502 with response body `{message: 'Internal Server Error'}`.

LA function updated as

```
export async function main(event, context, callback) {
```

Comment: Abhishek Rathore, How did you resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the callback and return directly.

```
exports.handler = async(event, context) => {
    lambda.invoke = util.promisify(lambda.invoke);
    return await lambda.invoke({
        FunctionName: 'yourLambda',
        Payload: yourPayload
    });
};
```